# Is this correspondence covariant or controvariant?

Tags: category-theory

I'm new to category theory and am trying a basic exercise.

Is the correspondence from $S$ to $\mathcal{P}(S)$, which assigns to $f:S\rightarrow T$ the mapping $\mathcal{P}(S)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(T)$ taking $X\subset S$ to $f(X)\subset T$ covariant or controvariant?

My attempt:
First, I need to check that it really is a functor, so I need to verify that it preserves the identity morphism. If we have an identity morphism in $S$, it should get taken to the identity morphism in $T$. Not really sure how to justify that, it just looks like it should be the case.

Next, I need to look at function compositions. Does that mean that I need to look at the order of composition for two functions $f:S\rightarrow T$ and $g:T\rightarrow U$?

Comment: Yes, I'm very confused.

From what I've understood: a covariant functor preserves the order of composition, while a contravariant functor reverses it.

The identity morphism is a morphism such that if you compose it with any other morphism, whether before or after, you just get that other morphism.

I'm not really sure about proving $id(X)$ and $X$ are equal.

$f(X)$ is the image of set $X$ (a subset of $S$) under the map $f:S\rightarrow T$

Comment: My understanding is that a functor $F$ from $C$ to $D$ assigns every $f:X\rightarrow Y$ in $C$ to an $F(f):F(X)\rightarrow F(Y)$. In my example, does $S$ correspond to $C$, and $\mathcal{P}(S)$? If so, then what's $T$? Is it another subset of $S$?

Comment: Or does $S$ correspond to $C$, and $T$ to $D$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A contravariant functor reverses not only the direction of the composition, but also the *domain* and *codomain*.

So, a contravariant functor $F$ must assign to an arrow $f:A\to B$ an arrow $F(f):F(B)\to F(A)$.

This in itself answers your question: the (so called 'covariant powerset functor') $\mathcal P$ is **covariant**, because, as you defined it, for an arrow $f:S\to T$ in $\bf Set$, it assigns an arrow $\mathcal P(S)\to\mathcal P(T)$.

[Now arrows in $\bf Set$ are functions between sets, so here $S$ and $T$ plays the role of arbitrary sets and $f$ is a function.]

The 'contravariant powerset functor' is contravariant: on objects (=sets) it is the same, but for an arrow (=function) $f:S\to T$ it assigns the preimage function $\mathcal P(T)\to\mathcal P(S)$ which maps $\mathcal P(T)\ni Y\,\mapsto\, f^{-1}(Y)\in\mathcal P(S)$.

You can also verify that compositions are preserved in both cases, in the appropriate way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the part about the domain and codomain not having been reversed, it's the part about verifying that compositions are preserved.

Comment: Do I need to show that for $f:S\rightarrow T$ and $g:T\rightarrow U$, it assigns $\mathcal{P}(S) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(T) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(U)$ to $f\circ g$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the opposite, i.e. it assigns $f\circ g$ to $\mathcal{P}(S)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(T)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(U)$?

Comment: All I need to show is $\mathcal{P}(f\circ g)=\mathcal{P}(f)\circ\mathcal{P}(g)$, which is pretty obvious.
Thanks for your clear explanation! :)